# importing a whole project into Maven (Eclipse Juno)

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, macos, maven

I have a folder that contains some Java code, written specifically for Linux.

There is a `pom.xml` file and two folders called: `src` and `build`

I have installed Eclipse Juno on my Mac (10.7.5) and I understand it already has Maven included. On the Linux machine, the code is executed by entering `mvn package` at the command line.

But after this stage, during the execution of the build artifact, it doesn't run on my Mac, because some of the commands are specific to Linux (I am told).

How do I import the whole project into Maven on my Mac? I mean where do I copy the folders and pom file?

Thank you,
 H

Comment: What specific error/s are you getting?

Comment: Maven is portable enough. You may need to define some profiles which will be activated based on the OS with some specific dependencies for each OS as well.

Comment: First, I run the command `mvn clean package` and I get a `BUILD SUCCESS` but then when I move into the `build` folder that was created as a result of the previous step (cd build) I need to locate the generated .jar file that shows the current date (java -jar foo-2013-04-05.jar –m classes/.......). After this step, I get the following:

Comment: ERROR: /usb/bin/lsb_release not found !ETA: 01:52   
ERROR: /usr/bin/lshw not found !

Comment: Since the error occurs during execute the build artifact by using `java -jar xxx.jar -m ...`. Then the issue should not relate to the Maven. AFAIU it is a different OS environment  for the runtime issue instead. Please update your question that there is an error during executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complementing Evgeniy Dorofeev's answer:

If your project is in a GIT repository and you use eGit, you might want to import it like this:

```
File->Import->Git->Projects from Git
```

After the import you can convert your project to a Maven project and it will update the project settings.

Comment: Thanks Paulo. My project is not in a GIT repository. I downloaded and installed m2e on my Eclipse Juno IDE and now it shows it under `already installed software` but `Maven` doesn't appear in my `Import` menu. How can I specify that in the IDE that it's there?

Comment: Taking a look at my plugins, I have downloaded m23-wtp as well. I always download both when installing new versions of Eclipse. Maybe you can give it a shot.

Answer (score 5):

You can leave the maven project where it is. Go to

```
File->import->Maven->Existing Maven Projects->Root directory
```

and select the maven project dir.

If you cannot see Maven in Import menu it means you need to add maven plugin (m2e) to your Juno. The fact that mvn runs from command line means only that maven is installed on your PC.

Comment: Thank you. When I go to `Eclipse` `Help` `Install New Software` and look at `What is already installed` it shows that `m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse` is already installed. But I cannot see `Maven` in my `Import` menu which (like you mentioned) means I need to add `maven plugin (m2e)` to my Juno. You mean my Juno IDE, Right? How do I do that? I thought I had already done that, and that's why it shows it under `already installed software`

Comment: My Juno for Windows did not have pre-installed m2e. To install goto Help->Eclipse marketplace -> find m2e

Comment: @Joshua The same thing is happening to me i.e I can see m2e under installed software but not getting Maven option under "import" option. How did u solve ur problem ?

Comment: This question goes back to one year ago, so I'm afraid I don't quite recall, but I think I did a fresh install and then imported all the libs from GIT. That's my recollection from last year. Sorry I cannot be more helpful...